# How to extend an Interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I need to add a new method (MethodC) to an interface but only for one specific class.  Rather than clogging up the current interface (IMyInterface), I'd like to use another interface for this one class.  This new interface would contain just the one new method (MethodC).  But the class uses the new interface also needs to use methods in IMyInterface.

I'm not sure how that can be structured.  I send back type IMyInterface from a factory method.  I don't know how the second interface can be sent back or if I can cast to it sometime later.

```
IMyInterface
- MethodA()
- MethodB()

//new interface for single class
IMyInterfaceExtend
- MethodC()

//factory method definition
IMyInterface Factory()

IMyInterface myi = StaticClass.Factory()
myi.MethodA()
myi.MethodB()
// sometime later
// I know this doesn't work but kind of where I'm wanting to go
((IMyInterfaceExtend)myi).MethodC()
```

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Have you considered just "inheriting" from the old interface? `public interface IMyInterfaceExtend : IMyInterface` ?

Comment: And why wouldn't the cast work? Presumably the underlying class would implement that interface, and in production code you would ideally check to make sure the object you got back really implements that interface. Though I must say, hidden interfaces are rarely a sign of good design.

Comment: If only one class will implement the new interface, why would you want to use it? Any time you use the new interface, you could just specify the class instead... The only reason I can think of would be for mocking, really.

Comment: Maybe an extension method for IMyInterface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface BaseInterface
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }

    void Method1();
}

public interface ExtendedInterface
{
    string FulllName { get; set; }

    void Method2();
}

public class ClassA : BaseInterface
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void Method1()
    { 
    }
}

public class ClassB : BaseInterface, ExtendedInterface
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public void Method1()
    {
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If the factory is sending back BaseInterface, how do I use ExtendedInterface?  Up cast?

Comment: @4thSpace Ye just cast the result using the As key word. - `IMyInterface myi =  StaticClass.Factory(); var extended = mui as IMyInterfaceExtend;`